# In emacs, can I have one set of line-wrap settings for code and one for text?

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

After quite a lot of experimentation, I think that I like:

```
(setq truncate-lines nil)
(setq word-wrap t)
```

for text editing, but

```
(setq truncate-lines t)
(setq word-wrap nil)
```

for programming.

In all modes, I like:

```
(setq fill-column 80)
```

so that I can use `M-q` and `C-u M-q` to flow text to 80 columns, but I also find that I dislike `auto-fill` mode and would never like it to be on.

I'm also not that keen on `visual-line-mode` (or at least the bit of it that isn't `word-wrap`)

Is there some incantation I can put in my `.emacs` file that will make me happy?

I define happy to be: 'it all just does what I want and I need never think about this again'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `prog-mode-hook` and `text-mode-hook` to set these variables:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(lambda ()
    (setq truncate-lines nil
          word-wrap t)))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(lambda ()
    (setq truncate-lines t
          word-wrap nil)))
```

Comment: not to forget, all programming modes haven't actually been derived from prog-mode. the first piece in the answer may not work for some programming modes

Comment: This would be a perfect answer if it worked! I've added those lines to my .emacs file but I just seem to get the default editing mode for all files.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden depending on your Emacs version, `prog-mode-hook` might not be defined (for example, I don't have it on Emacs 23.3.1; you can check if you get some documentation using `C-h v prog-mode-hook`). If this is the case, you'll have to add hooks for all programming modes you use (or upgrade to Emacs 24).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not giving source-code in my answer, but i can assure you that the setup you have in mind is in deed possible. It only depends on your definition of "programming modes". Most modes come with a so called hook-function (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html ). These are basically functions that are executed when a mode is loaded. Such a hook would then adjust the settings you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

(setq truncate-lines t) still does not work?

Culprit might be another mode. Visual-line-mode was mine (global-visual-line-mode), so I had to put the disabling function into the hook:

```
(add-hook 'neotree-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
         (visual-line-mode -1)
         (setq truncate-lines t)))
```